# Why is GitLab keep sending me notification emails

Tags: email, notifications, gitlab

I have turned off Global notification level and the notification on all my projects and even changed my e-mail address in order to avoid gitlab sending me commit messages, it seem their notification system is bugged... When will this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Link to repo? Did you leave your email in your Gitlab ci yml?